# How do I declare and reassign a variable in React Class Component to store a setTimeout reference?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, settimeout

Being used to React function components I normally declare consts inside the function. But now I have to declare a variable in a class component and have tried three different ways:

```js
  constructor(props: HWTrendChartProps) {
    super(props);
    testVarible = 'this is a test'; // 'testVarible' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)
  }
```

```js
  constructor(props: HWTrendChartProps) {
    super(props);
    this.testVarible = 'this is a test'; // Property 'testVarible' does not exist on type 'classname'.ts(2339)
  }
```

```
private static timeoutRef: any; // works but have to re-assign using classname.timeoutRef = blahblah;
```

I am trying to store a `setTimeout` reference in the class component so I may `clearTimeout` from `componentWillUnmount`. I don't want to add it to state if I can avoid it.

Comment: use state 
inside constructor
   constructor(props: HWTrendChartProps) {
    super(props);
   this.state={
    testVarible: 'this is a test';
}
  }

**then access it by typing this.state.testVariable**

Comment: The second type you tried should work, also working for me in the fiddle. I think the way you are calling setTimeout has some issue. can you post the part where you call setTimeout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the property as a field of the class:

```
class MyClass {
 private testVariable: string
 constructor(props: HWTrendChartProps) {
    super(props);
    this.testVarible = 'this is a test'; // Property 'testVarible' does not exist on type 'classname'.ts(2339)
  }
}
```